# O certo seria "você possui 7 dias de férias agendadas" ou "você possui 7 dias de férias agendados"?

Tags: concordância-verbal

Estou tendo problemas com concordância

No caso da frase do título, o verbo deve concordar com *dias* ou com *férias*? Ou poderia concordar com ambos?

Comment: *de férias*, ao meu ver, é um adjunto adnominal de *dias (sub. concreto)*; logo, eu escreveria: *Você possui 7 dias de férias agendados* ou *Você possui, agendados, 7 dias de férias*

Comment: @ValdeirPsr é verdade, acho que o masculino seria a aposta segura considerando isso. Acho que fiquei perdido imaginando o conceito de (férias-agendadas) haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode concordar com qualquer dos dois, mas com significados distintos:

> 1. Você possui 7 dias de férias agendados.

É o uso mais comum, em que "de férias" qualifica os "dias" e se quer dizer que os 7 dias (desse tipo: de férias) estão agendados. Indicando graficamente: "**7 (dias-de-férias) agendados**". Para um dia apenas, a concordância seria também em número: "1 dia de férias agendado".

> 2. Você possui 7 dias de férias agendadas.

Indicando graficamente: "**7 dias de (férias-agendadas)**". Aqui as férias é que estão agendadas, então é preciso se estar num contexto em que a expressão "férias agendadas" faça sentido. Por exemplo, em algumas instituições, desde que outras condições sejam satisfeitas, férias podem ter ser requisitadas a posteriori, ou seja, podem ser gozadas antes de serem oficializadas. Isso cria dois conceitos de férias: as "férias agendadas" e as "férias não agendadas".

A [UFPE](https://www.ufpe.br/busca?p_p_id=101&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_101_struts_action=%2Fasset_publisher%2Fview_content&_101_assetEntryId=1261759&_101_type=content&_101_groupId=943702&_101_urlTitle=realizar-pagamento-de-ferias-nao-agendadas&_101_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ufpe.br%2Fen%2Fbusca%3Fp_p_id%3D3%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_3_advancedSearch%3Dfalse%26_3_groupId%3D0%26_3_keywords%3DCurso%2Bde%2BF%25C3%25A9rias%2Bdo%2BDepartamento%2Bde%2BF%25C3%25ADsica%26_3_assetCategoryIds%3D22611%26_3_delta%3D20%26_3_resetCur%3Dfalse%26_3_cur%3D4%26_3_struts_action%3D%252Fsearch%252Fsearch%26_3_format%3D%26_3_assetTagNames%3Ddcm%26_3_andOperator%3Dtrue%26_3_formDate%3D1441824476958&inheritRedirect=true),
por exemplo, estabelece normas para "*Realizar Pagamento de Férias Não Agendadas*", que são definidas como "férias gozadas e não agendadas", e uso semelhante é feito pela [UDESC](https://www.udesc.br/ceart/rh/tecnicos/ferias).

Nessas situações se poderia dizer, e.g., "Você possui 29 dias de férias agendadas e 1 dia de férias não agendadas e, portanto, já esgotou as férias deste ano."

Comment: Não sei se é só comigo, mas ainda fiquei mais confuso eheheh. Pode dar mais uns exemplos?

Comment: @JorgeB. Estranho muito, mas adicionei os trechos em negrito que, espero, podem ajudar.

Comment: Ajudou muito, devia ser falta de café pela manhã eheheh

Comment: @JorgeB. Na verdade essa resposta me parece inclusive um pouco prolixa, mas não consegui formular melhor agora.

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Não tinha imaginado o conceito de _'férias-agendadas'_ como uma única "entidade", mas fiquei imaginando se esse conceito já não existiria sem a ideia de outros tipos de férias. Em outras palavras, se todas as férias fossem agendadas.

Comment: @VictorPerszel Penso que poderia existir sem outros tipos de férias, mas então, se há apenas um tipo, isso significaria que "férias agendadas" seria redundante.